# Difference of String[] a and String a [] 

Tags: android, arrays, string

Suppose a is a group of strings.

I can not understand the difference between `String[] a` and 
`String a[]`
Is both of them have the same meaning?I need the answer based on android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking about Java, then, yes, both have the same meaning.

`String[] a` is preferred since it keeps the entire type definition together and visually distinct from the identifier.

`String a[]` is only in the language to make it easier for `C++` and `C` programmers to learn.  The Java language creators were initially trying to convince C++ developers to learn Java by adopting a familiar syntax.

Comment: Android is a mobile stack, not a programming language.  Many of the stacks APIs are exposed to Java programs that run on top of the Dalvik VM.